# How can I get rid of this error in active admin rails app NoMethodError in Admin::Records#show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, will-paginate, kaminari

I have installed active admin gem to my rails app. I integrated with my models well. After I login to admin panel and want to view my records it shows this error. This error comes in updating and submitting the button. But internally the file is updated and edited, there is no side effect of this.

I have integrated my records with will paginate.

I have added this file to my `/config/initializers/kaminari.rb` too but couldnot solved...

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

The complete error is:

```
undefined method `total_count' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
Did you mean?  total_entries
```

Extracted source (around line #124):

```
122        arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
123      else
124        super
125      end
126    end
127  end
```

> `` Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
> activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:124:in `method_missing'
> activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:94:in `method_missing'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb:23:in `title'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb:16:in `build'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `active_admin_comments_for'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/show_page_helper.rb:18:in `active_admin_comments'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/show_page_helper.rb:12:in `default_main_content'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb:23:in `main_content'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:90:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:89:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:75:in `block in build_page_content'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:74:in `build_page_content'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:48:in `block in build_page'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:47:in `build_page'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:2:in `block in __home_madhav__rbenv_versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_activeadmin_____ea_f_fd__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb___2047537122749437189_69832972317760'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
> arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `new'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6038ea6f8fd0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `__home_madhav__rbenv_versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_activeadmin_____ea_f_fd__app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb___2047537122749437189_69832972317760'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:104:in `_render_template'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
> /home/madhav/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
> activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:107:in `to_html'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
> responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:211:in `respond_with'
> inherited_resources (1.7.2) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:13:in `show'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
> activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
> actionview (5.0.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
> warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
> warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
> warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
> activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
> web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
> web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
> web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
> web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
> railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
> railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
> railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
> sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
> activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
> actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
> rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
> railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
> puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
> puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
> puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
> puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
> puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread' ``

Screenshot of error is:

[image: Image of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled the active admin comments. Previously, comments were enabled by default in the file
`/config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
# You can completely disable comments:
# config.comments = false
```

I disabled the active admin comments by changing the code:

```
# You can completely disable comments:
config.comments = false
```

And finally get rid of that error.
Thank you all.